# MVC date format issue in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently attempting to set the date format within my ASP.NET MVC application.

I am using the following code to accomplish this

**model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Of_Birth { get; set; }
```

**view:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Of_Birth)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Of_Birth)
        </div>
```

This works as expected in 'Details' mode.  However, when I enter 'Edit' mode the field displays as follows

[image]

The desired date format appears in the text box, along with what looks like a default date picker.   This is obviously not what I was looking for.  I simply wanted the date to be formatted correctly.  I was also planning on using the jQuery date picker so I don't really want the default date picker either.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution (assuming you want to let all your edit fields for dates look the same) is to replace the template for `Html.EditorFor()` for objects of type `DateTime`. That way you can build any behavior you want into the template itself, thus also keeping the view logic in the view layer.

The basic way to do that is to create a file called `DateTime.cshtml` (I think - it's `DateTime.ascx` when using the WebForms view engine, but you're using Razor...) and place it in `~/Views/Shared/EditTemplates`.

Brad Wilson has an [excellent guide on his blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) that I strongly recommend you to check out.